# Nextjs getStaticProps failing to read firebase firestore data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I am trying to read my data from firestore using getStaticProps, but somehow, it is rendering an empty page. I must say, when I use useEffect, the data renders, but the moment I change it to getStaticProps, it returns an empty page. This is how the code looks like at the moment

```
import { db } from '@/Firebase';
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

const reference = collection(db, "students");

function Card(props) {
    const { studentsData } = props
    
    return (
    <div>
        <p>This is just a test</p>
        {studentsData && studentsData.map(students => (
                <div className="l">
                    <p>{students.name}</p>
                </div>
            ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
    const students = await getDocs(reference);
    const studentsData = students.docs.map(doc => ({id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }))
    console.log(studentsData);

    return {
        props: { studentsData }
    }
}

export default Card
```

I have followed the docs and multiple tutorial blogs online, but it is now working for me. How and where could I be going wrong?

Comment: You have a typo, it should be `getStaticProps`.

Comment: @ivanatias i fixed that but its still the same

Comment: Is this component a `page` folder component?

Comment: Its a component in the components folder. Could it maybe be firebase? Because even when I console log, it returns nothing.

Comment: `getStaticProps`, `getServerSideProps` and `getStaticPaths` can only be used on page components.

Comment: @ivanatias you mean as in that logic in the Card component has to be in the index.js file?

Comment: Or just any other `page` folder component. Point is, if it's not a page component, it can't use Next.js' data fetching functions.